# Force \endlinechar to reset before the end of last line

Tags: catcodes

I am creating a macro which should write its argument as a literal string to an external file. This is its current state:

```
\newcommand{\mycmd}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \endlinechar=`\^^J
    \catcode`\^^M=9
    \catcode`\^^I=12
    \catcode`\ =12
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \@mycmd
}

\long\def\@mycmd#1{%
    \endgroup
    \newwrite\myfile
    \immediate\openout\myfile{file.out}%
    \immediate\write\myfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \immediate\closeout\myfile
}
```

And its usage is as follows:

```
\mycmd{
some text ...
text on new line
    this text will be indented
et cetera
}
```

This works correctly in regards to writing the text in the file, but after the last line of the macro (i.e., the one with the `}`), an Omega character `Ω` is displayed, which I suppose is due to the fact that `\endlinechar` is still aliased to `10`.

I know I could simply end that line with a comment, but I plan on sharing this code with others and I would like to automate the fix.

Comment: The `\newwrite` declaration must not be inside `\@mycmd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\endlinechar` is inserted as soon as TeX needs to fetch a line of input, but not tokenized.

So you can declare that, after the group finishes, the `\endlinechar` (which is still `^^J`) is active, with a definition that just reinstates the normal category code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycmd}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \endlinechar=`\^^J
    \catcode`\^^M=9
    \catcode`\^^I=12
    \catcode`\ =12
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \@mycmd
}

\newwrite\myfile % must go outside the macros!

\newcommand{\@mycmd}[1]{%
    \immediate\openout\myfile{\jobname.out}%
    \immediate\write\myfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \immediate\closeout\myfile
    \endgroup\@check@endline
}
\newcommand{\@check@endline}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`^^J \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\@makeother\^^J}%
  \catcode`^^J=\active
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text before.
\mycmd{
some text ...
text on new line
    this text will be indented
et cetera
}
This is not gobbled.

\end{document}
```

Beware that you ***don't*** want `\newwrite` inside `\@mycmd` or a new stream would be allocated each time you call `\mycmd`.

I also recommend *not* to pursue this strategy: editors have very different and sometimes peculiar ideas about how to cope with the line breaks issued by the user.

What does the `\@check@endline` macro do? It sets `^^J` to an active character, giving it the meaning “change the category code of `^^J` back to 12”. So the character disappears and it being active is forgotten.

Comment: @egreg Interesting approach. Would the result be different if you replaced `\aftergroup\@check@endline\endgroup` with `\endgroup\@check@endline`? Unrelated: the space in `{\@makeother\^^J }` should be removed.

Comment: My last sentence relates to tests like this: `\mycmd{...}%
This^^Jis not gobbled.` where the `%` ends a line. There you see the space token append a glue item to the horizontal list.

Comment: @frougon Yes, the `\aftergroup` is not really necessary (a leftover from earlier code). And the space was too. Thanks for noting.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation seems correct to me. If 0 ≤ `\endlinechar` ≤ 255, a character with TeX-internal code `\endlinechar` is appended to each line *very early*, even before tokenization has started for said line. In your example, as soon as `\@mycmd` is expanded, TeX reads and tokenizes input until it has one argument, which in this case goes up to and including the closing `}`. The line containing this character thus gets the terminator obtained from `` \endlinechar=`\^^J ``, i.e. a character with TeX-internal code 10.

Only after this is the `\@mycmd` macro call replaced by its replacement text, starting with `\endgroup`, and only after that is the `\endgroup` executed, which restores the normal value of `\endlinechar`.

Since the catcode of characters with TeX-internal code 10 is 12 aka “other” (this is the default in plain TeX as well as in LaTeX, and isn't changed in the example), when the added character is tokenized, it yields a (10, 12) character token, which causes character 10 in the current font (which has encoding OT1 here) to be written to the output file, which is indeed an `Ω` (cf `texdoc encguide` p. 19):

[image]

The following code uses a macro taking a delimited argument to eat the unwanted (10, 12) explicit character token:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% \newwrite out of the macro def., as egreg recommended
\newwrite\myfile

\newcommand{\mycmd}{%
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \endlinechar=`\^^J
    \catcode`\^^M=9
    \catcode`\^^I=12
    \catcode`\ =12
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \my@cmd
}

\newcommand{\my@cmd}[1]{%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\openout\myfile{file.out}%
    \immediate\write\myfile{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \immediate\closeout\myfile
    \my@normalizeEndline
}

\@ifdefinable{\my@normalizeEndline}{%
  \def\my@normalizeEndline#1^^J{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycmd{
  some text ...
  text on new line
  this text will be indented
  et cetera
}
% \mbox{}% Uncomment if you want an output file (PDF or DVI) to be written

\end{document}
```

Note: with this technique, users must not put a `%` after the `}`, otherwise TeX will look further for the (10, 12) explicit character token. Another possibility, with its own downsides, would be to use `\@ifnextchar^^J{\@gobble}{}%` instead of `\my@normalizeEndline` in `\my@cmd`.